# add auth or dissable /metrics endpoint for prometheus client

Tags: openshift, prometheus

I am using Prometheus on OpenShift platform. Authentication is handled by OpenShift for Prometheus and all its sub domains except /metrics endpoint. 
It bypasses all authentication and shows Prometheus go client metrics plain texted.

Is it possible to somehow force OpenShift authentication on prometheus/metrics endpoint or to disable that endpoint since I don't really need go client metrics?

I know that node_exporters have flags to control certain collectors but I couldn't find it for Prometheus client itself.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure about openshift auth, but you can add basic auth to the '/metrics' endpoint. Alternatively prometheus can also support TLS.

Add the following to the 'scrape_config' section in your prometheus config file (prometheus.yml by default)

```
basic_auth:
    username: "admin"
    password: "password"
```

More info can be found in the official prometheus documentation linked [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config)